# select Firebase data with queryOrdered(byChild: "name") queryEqual

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

i want to select a specific name from my firebase-table (look at the picture). The result to print is always empty. The selected name should be "manni". What is wrong in my code? Thx a lot.

```
   @IBAction func BTSelect(_ sender: Any) {

   DBref = Database.database().reference()

    let query = DBref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: "manni")
    query?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            print("childSnapshot:->  \(childSnapshot)")
        }
    })

}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ugLu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `queryOrdered(byChild: "name")` if each child node has a **property** name. But in your case, you're querying a node named `name` and you want to filter on the **value** of the child nodes. To do that, use `queryOrderedByValue`:

```
let query = DBref?.child("name").queryOrderedByValue).queryEqual(toValue: "manni")
```

This first orders the child nodes of `name` on their value, and then only returns the ones matching `manni`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Now it`s running. But i can not go with firebase further. There is no possibility to select incremental like in SQL ( where field like "%%"). This is very disappointing. Otherwise its a great solution, but a NOSQL-DB should do this. I'm going to complain at google ;))

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
let query = DBref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: "manni")
```

to this:

```
let query = DBref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "-L5o1LyZRP3J_D-OiguB").queryEqual(toValue: "manni")
```

since the `child: name` is not equal to `manni`. A child inside `name` is equal to manni.

P.S.: i might have copied this wrong `-L5o1LyZRP3J_D-OiguB`

The child name is a parent node(not equal to anything), and all those nodes with randomids are the children of the child `name`.

If you want more than one value to be retrieved, it needs to have the same key (key:value), you can then do the below:

You can change your database like this:

```
myapp2go-app
     randomid
          name:manni
     randomid
          name:manni
     randomid
          name:ulli
     randomid
          name:Test
     randomid
          name:alf
     randomid
          name:ulf
```

then in your query, keep it like this:

```
 let query = DBref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: "manni")
```

Comment: if i do this:     byChild: "-L5o1LyZRP3J_D-OiguB" like you suggested i only get one name. But the result should be 2 names !? but it did'nt even work your way.

Comment: no the result is correct, you get one name because the other one has a different randomid, please check your database above. Each `manni` has a different key, they need to have the same key.

Comment: also check this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/142 might help you

Comment: Thank you for tips. This is my way to save the data:     DBref?.child("name").childByAutoId().setValue(TFInput.text!)  
How can i get rid of this randomid ?

Comment: childByAutoId() is generating the random id and setValue(TFInput.text!) is the value like manni, ulf.. So I guess do this, `DBref?.childByAutoId().child("name").setValue(TFInput.text!)`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Now it`s running. But i can not go with firebase further. There is no possibility to select incremental like in SQL ( where field like "%%"). This is very disappointing. Otherwise its a great solution, but a NOSQL-DB should do this. I'm going to complain at google ;))